Why doesn't char-pointer function parameter give seg fault error when modifying the string?
A character array declared as char str[] = "Gear"; can be modified but char* str = "Gear"; is a string literal that cannot be modified and gives seg fault error if we try to change the characters.
In the program below, when the parameter in the function PrintStr is declared as char* str and modified later on, it prints the string without giving a seg fault error.
void PrintStr(char* str)
{
   str[0] = 'D';    
   puts(str);    
}     
int main()
{
   char str[] = "Gear";    
   PrintStr(str);   
   return 0;    
}

Why does it not make any difference when char* str is declared as a function parameter?
I was expecting seg fault error when I declared PrintStr(char* str) and tried to modify the string in the function str[0] = 'D'.

If it isn't fully clear from the linked duplicate, the parameter list is not relevant for what you are looking for. The definition of str in main is relevant. If it was char str*="Gear"; then you would really try to modify a literal. But in your code, a copy of the literal is stored in the array that you pass to your function.

The reason you cannot modify a char *var = "Cannot be changed"; is not because it's a pointer but because var points to read-only memory. Because in main you've declared str as a char[] and pass it to PrintStr, then str in PrintStr points to a memory location which is not read-only, hence it allows you to modify it.

The proposed dupe may indirectly contain the answer but the main focus is different so IMO it's not a clear dupe with a clear answer for this question. I vote to reopen.

In a function parameter char *x is 100% equivalent to char x[] (and vice-versa). To prevent attempt to change a string literal, I've seen const char *x = "string literal"; vs char y[] = "copy of string literal";. Just remember to always honor the const-ness of an object.
